# What would be the equivalent predicates in SWI prolog?

Tags: prolog

In the book "Expert systems in prolog" I've hit a roadblock. The book defines a simple shell as follows:

```
solve :-
   abolish(known, 3),
   define(known, 3),
   top_goal(X),
   write('The answer is '),
   write(X),
   nl.
solve :-
   write('No answer found.'),
   nl.
```

However, the predicate `define` doesn't seem to be a built-in predicate in SWI-Prolog. The purpose of define is to ensure the predicate `known/3` is defined in the system after abolish is called to remove any previous definitions of `known/3`. `known/3` itself is used to mark if an attribute/value pair is in the database or not. I've tried using `assert/1`:

```
assert(known(Y,A,V)).
```

But I'm not sure if that's correct.

Also, in

```
write('The answer is '), write(X), nl.
```

The listener reports that there's a syntax error and that an operator was expected. Yet, in the second definition of solve, there's no issue.

What would be the equivalent for SWI-Prolog, and how can I fix my syntax error? Thanks for your help!

Comment: You might consider a more introductory Prolog textbook before this one. This book has some quite special code shown in it, some of it also a bit outdated in its style.

Comment: I'm familiar with the basics: facts, rules, predicates, clauses, variables, atoms, and unification. google_predicate_with_arity(X) :- do_not_know_definition(X). ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that in SWI-Prolog you should be able to use `dynamic(known/3)` to achieve the same as what `define(known, 3)` is supposed to be doing. I guess that for your needs instead of `abolish(known, 3), define(known, 3)`, you should be using `retractall(known(_,_,_))`.

Say, you have a predicate that should succeed if a condition is satisfied, and fail otherwise, and you query:

```
?- a(7).
```

At this point, either you have somewhere in your database a `a(7).`, then the query succeeds. Or you don't have a `a(7).`, but Prolog knows about the predicate `a/1`, so the query fails. Or, `a/1` is not defined at all, and you get an error (exception).

What [`abolish`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=abolish/1) does is to completely erase any knowledge of a predicate, so that it is not defined at all, and you get an error if you try to evaluate it. What [`retractall`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=retractall/1) does is that it removes all clauses of a predicate, and makes sure that the system knows about the predicate. What [`dynamic`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=dynamic/1) does is that it declares a predicate to the system at compile time or at run time (!) so that a call to the predicate is not an error, even if the predicate itself has no clauses.

```
?- a(7).
ERROR: toplevel: Undefined procedure: a/1 (DWIM could not correct goal)
?- dynamic(a/1).
true.

?- a(7).
false.

?- abolish(a/1).
true.

?- a(7).
ERROR: toplevel: Undefined procedure: a/1 (DWIM could not correct goal)
?- retractall(a(_)).
true.

?- a(7).
false.

?- assertz(a(7)).
true.

?- a(7).
true.
```